# How to handle log events with the npmlog library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, events, event-handling

this might be an easy question for you but I am struggling with it.
I want to catch the events thrown by the npmlog library as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmlog

How do I create an event listener on those? There is no .on() function neither can I create an instance of log beforehand.

```
import * as log from 'npmlog';
log.error('problem', 'some message');

// What I would like to do:
log.on("error", ()=>{do something})
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The eventName is `log`, `log.<level>`, or `<prefix>`.

```
log.on('log', function (record) {
    // Use log record
});

log.error('error', 'error message');
```